# java: count opening and closing tag pair

Tags: java

I have below text

```
`h1` text  `/h1`        `i` text  `/i`            `u` text  `/u`
```

Here pair `h1` `/h1` , `i` `/i` , `u` `/u` perfectly exist so this text should be passed. Now take this text

```
`h1` text  `/h1`        `i` text  `/i`            `u` text  `/u
```

here the `u` `/u` combination is missing. So the above text failed.

I tried this

```
    String startTags[] = {"`b`","`h1`","`h2`","`h3`","`h4`","`h5`","`h6`","`ul`","`li`","`i`","`u`"};
    String endTags[] = {"`/b`","`/h1`","`/h2`","`/h3`","`/h4`","`/h5`","`/h6`","`/ul`","`/li`","`/i`","`/u`"};

        for(int i=0;i<startTags.length;i++){
            if(str.indexOf(startTags[i])!=-1){
                System.out.println(">>>>"+startTags[i]);
                startTagCount++;
            }
            if(str.indexOf(endTags[i])!=-1){System.out.println("+++"+endTags[i]);
                endTagCount++;
            }                
        }

if(startTagCount==endTagCount){
 //TEXT IS OK
}else{
 // TEXT FAILED
}
```

It passes below text instead getting failed

```
`h5`Is your question about programming? `/h5`
`b` bbbbbbbbbbbbbb`/b`
`b` bbbbbbbbbbbbbb`/b
```

Any better solution or regex in java ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this problem cannot be solved by (strict) regular expressions, because the language you describe is not a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), it extends the language {a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup>}, which is a well-known non-regular language.

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is making sure all opening tags have matching closing tags, then you can use regular expressions.

Your code has a logic problem, in that you count all opening tags and all closing tags, but don't check if the opening tags and closing tags actually match. The startTagCount and endTagCount variables are not sufficient. I would suggest using a map, using the tag type as a key and the value as the count. Increment count on open tag, decrement count on close tag. Check for non-zero after scanning is complete.

What is the grammar of this "language"? Your approach might be not be proper validation. For example, this HTML has matching tag counts but is invalid:

```
<b><i>Invalid</b></i>
```